# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy generando el anulado de una factura utilizando un procedimiento de almacenado de mysql, si la factura se anula entonces debe generar la misma pero con una marca de agua.

El código donde llamo a ejecutar el procedimiento es el siguiente

```php
$id_venta = $_GET['venta'];

$query_procesar = mysqli_query($conectar, "CALL anular_factura($id_venta)");
$result_detalle = mysqli_num_rows($query_procesar);
```

Luego valido que se haya generado la tabla con los datos de la factura pero anulada y si es así debería generar la factura.

Aquí el código en donde valido y empiezo a obtener los datos de la factura para generar el pdf:

```php
if($result_detalle > 0){
    $anul = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_procesar);
    $cliente = $anul['cliente'];
    $anulada = '';
    
    $query_factura = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT f.id_venta, DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,
    DATE_FORMAT(f.fecha, '%H:%i:%s') AS hora, f.cliente, f.estatus,f.tipo_venta, f.pago,
                                        v.nombre AS nombre_vendedor, v.apellido AS apellido_vendedor,
                                        cl.id_cliente, cl.nombre, cl.apellido, cl.telefono,cl.direccion,cl.correo
                                        FROM ventas f
                                        INNER JOIN usuarios v
                                        ON f.id_usuario = v.id_usuario
                                        INNER JOIN clientes cl
                                        ON f.cliente = cl.nro
                                        WHERE f.id_venta = $id_venta AND f.cliente = $cliente AND f.estatus != 10");

$result_fact = mysqli_num_rows($query_factura);
```

Es en esta línea donde me dice que tengo el error pero no sé por qué.

> $result_fact = mysqli_num_rows($query_factura);

Pensé que podría tener un error en la sentencia SQL y la probe directamente en el MySQL y no tuve ningún inconveniente si me retorno los valores correctos

[image: Sentencia SQl]

Ojalá me puedan ayudar, gracias

He hecho lo que me han dicho para ver que es lo que falla en el `SELECT` y el error que me arroja el `SELECT` es el siguiente:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

primera vez que me sale ese error, si saben a que se debe les agradecería mucho si me dijeran como solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Seguro que tu conexión trabaja bien?

Comment: Si, la factura se anula correctamente, pero a la hora de obtener los datos de la factura de la base de datos es que ocurre el error

Comment: ¿Has validado de que `$anul = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_procesar); y $cliente = $anul['cliente'];`  te estén dando los valores que esperas?

Comment: Si, eso también esta correcto

Comment: Tras `mysqli_query()` deberías hacer lo siguiente: `if ($query_factura === false) { die(mysqli_error()); }`. Con eso te aparecerá por pantalla el motivo por el que la consulta falló. Tu consulta podría sufrir de inyección SQL, además de que **no compruebas que `$id_venta` y `$cliente` tengan valores válidos**.

Answer (score 0):

El error que mencionas dice que `$query_factura` ha vuelto con tipo boolean, es decir, true o false, y esto PUEDE ocurrir...

> Valores devueltos ¶
> Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query() retornará TRUE.
> Fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Entonces lo que debes hacer, es analizar en que casos esta consulta te devuelve valores booleanos. Para ello lo que debes realizar, son 2 cosas.

1. Ejecutar un echo de la consula (`echo $query;`). 
   Esto te permitirá obtener la consulta completa en ese momento, y ejecutarla de manera cruda en phpmyadmin.
   Pero antes, para analizarla debidamente, separala del `mysqli_query`:

   ```
   $query = "Acá poné la query";
   $query_factura = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);
   echo var_dump($query);
   ```
2. Ejecutar además, otro `echo var_dump()` pero esta vez, de `$query_factura`.
    Esto devolverá o el valor booleano, o el objeto. Si devuelve booleano, es que hay error en la consulta.

   ```
   echo var_dump($query_factura);
   ```

De este modo, lograras ver tu mismo, como es que llega a fallar tu `select`